# Undefined symbol curl_easy_init for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libcurl

When building my mini project on macOS/XCode/C++, I get the linker error mentioned in the subject line, and I don't understand why I get it, and what I can do to avoid it.

My code is extremely simple, it's essentially the code that was autogenerated by XCode during the creation of the project (a command line application), plus the two curl-related lines I added myself:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    CURL *easy_handle = curl_easy_init();
    
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The linker complains about the symbol *_curl_easy_init()* as being missing, even though I *have* added the libcurl.4.tbd framework to the project, and inspecting the details of the framework in XCode shows the that the symbol in question is exported. At least that's what it looks like.

So I'm really at a loss as to what the problem is and how to solve it. Thanks in advance for any hint or suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Despite appearances, it's not enough to add the framework to the list of Linked Frameworks in the Project Navigator in the left-hand pane.  You also have to add it to 'Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content' in the 'General' settings for your build target (which will be your application, in this case).

A couple of screenshots should make this clear.  In this case, I'm adding the SystemConfiguration framework to my build:

Before:
[image: Before]
After:
[image]
Then build your project again.

Comment: Thanks for your help including screen shots!! I don't have the "Linked Frameworks" subfolder under my "Frameworks" folder. In my case, I want to add the cURL framework to my project, so I click on the "+" sign in the right pane under "Frameworks, Libraries, etc.", select libcurl.4.tbd, and click OK. The result of this is that I see that tbd file under the Frameworks heading in the left pane, but that's it. Nothing is added in the right pane. Seems I do something incorrectly, but what?

Comment: I forget, but I'm not sure it has any effect anyway so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had to add the library under "Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries", and not under "Target > General > Frameworks and Libraries", even though it will appear under the latter as well, automatically.